# How to load an abandoned dependency with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a project in PHP with a dependency that has been abandoned and it's no longer available to download from github, so the command composer install will fail.

I can find the dependency in the vendor folder of the AWS server it's hosted in.

Is there a way I can load that dependency into the project to make it work locally?

I have zero experience with PHP and composer.

This is the excerpt of composer.json with the missing dependency:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    ...
    "d3lph1/laravel-configger": "~1.0"
    ...
}
```

And this is the composer.lock part:

```
    {
        "name": "d3lph1/laravel-configger",
        "version": "1.1",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/D3lph1/laravel-configger.git",
            "reference": "f964e5ad8b30a7b06a0787bfca9dbf093cc61db0"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/D3lph1/laravel-configger/zipball/f964e5ad8b30a7b06a0787bfca9dbf093cc61db0",
            "reference": "f964e5ad8b30a7b06a0787bfca9dbf093cc61db0",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "laravel/framework": "~5.3",
            "php": ">=5.4.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "D3lph1\\LaravelConfigger\\": "src",
                "D3lph1\\LaravelConfigger\\Tests\\": "tests"
            }
        },
        "notification-url": "https://packagist.org/downloads/",
        "license": [
            "MIT"
        ],
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Chertkov Bogdan",
                "email": "d3lph1.contact@gmail.com",
                "role": "Developer"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Persistent settings for your Laravel app",
        "homepage": "https://github.com/D3lph1/laravel-configger",
        "keywords": [
            "Settings",
            "config",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "time": "2017-08-16T13:46:10+00:00"
    },
```

Comment: You don't give any details, that means you can only get general answers in return. Something like: "Yes, it is possible, but it can be complicated.".

Comment: If the license allows this: why not publish your own copy of that library on Github?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KIKOSoftware, I added some more details.

Comment: @NicoHaase the license is MIT. I will have to check if it's possible to add it to a private repository.. but then how do I change where composer looks for the source?

Comment: Yeah, if the URL to the repository is changed, you need to update this in `composer.json` and `composer.lock`